# rotating buttons

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my IPhone application, I have five buttons with background image set.

At any time one button is active an the other one is inactive.

I want to display the five buttons in 3d style such that the active image is in front and the others are at the back but visible.

When the user clicks the inactive button, it should come to the front and the the other one should go back, with all the buttons rotating like 3d effect.

Can anyone suggest an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Cocos2d might be worth a look, it is very good (and not to hard) to make fancy things like this. http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/
Hope this helps.

Comment: can I do it using root view controller?

Comment: dont think so, you could try giving each button its own view